# When is ASP.Net 4 available on a server

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0

i was building a new small website for an existing client, and thought about building it with ASP.Net 4.
But in the apppoolsettings, i could only choose framework 2.0, so i guessed that 4.0 is not available on the server.

Is it something i have to install on the server, or will it be installed via windows update somewhere in time?

it's a win2008 standard server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly download and install it yourself, e.g. [from here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9cfb2d51-5ff4-4491-b0e5-b386f32c0992&displaylang=en). You want the full .NET 4, not the .NET 4 client profile - that doesn't include ASP.NET.

According to [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dseven/archive/2010/06/14/net-4-on-windows-update.aspx) it will eventually become an optional update on Windows servers (if it isn't already).

Answer (score 1):

you just need to install .net framework 4.0 on server.